# Global variable undefined inside a function

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I am using webpack and have one global variable inside a module, when I try to return it from inside a function I get `undefined`. I do not really understand the scope since I thought I can access global variables from a functional and return them.
here is my code:

```
import Gameboard from './factory/gameboard';
import Player from './factory/player';
import helpers from './helpers';
import dom from './dom';

const game = (() => {
  let gameStatus = false;
  var player;
  var computer;
  let turn = 0;

  const getPlayers = () => {
    const name = 'Player1';
    player = Player(name);
    computer = Player('Computer');
  };

  const whosTurn = function whosTurn() {
    if (turn % 2 === 0) {
      return player;
    }
    return computer;
  };

  const getPeg = (index = null) => {
    const playerTurn = whosTurn();
    if (playerTurn.getName() === 'Computer') {
      helpers().computerMove();
      dom().createPlayerBoard(playerBoard);
    } else {
      const gameboard = computerBoard;
      makeAttack(playerTurn, gameboard, index);
      dom().createCompBoard(gameboard);
    }
  };

  return {
    getPlayers,
    whosTurn,
    getPeg,
  };
});

export {
  game as
  default
};
```

I want the `whosTurn` function to return me the player or computer variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't the players just an array? You can use a counter based on the current turn and mod it by the player count to get the current index.

Comment: `if (turn % 2 === 0) { ` how is `turn` being updated? And I do not think you mean to say "global"

Comment: the variable turn is updated in other function, I did not add it here to reduce the code

Comment: Even using an array, the function ```whosTurn``` is returning ```undefined```

Comment: Well did you ever initialize `getPlayers` ? In no, then it will be undefined. My guess is you need to show how you are using this.

Comment: I just initialize ```getPlayers``` inside ```whosTurn``` and is returning me the players

Comment: you never initialize `player` and `computer`, because you don't call `getPlayers` inside `game`. so both are undefinied and hence your `whosTurn`-function returns undefined, too.